# Deprecation of Facebook offline_access, how to handle on Windows Phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-oauth, facebook-access-token

I am working on a Windows Phone app that utilizes the Facebook API. To do that I need the user to login and authorize my app, so that I can get an access_token. I've already done that, it works fine.

**The question:** how to keep using the Facebook API on the next launch of the app without having the user to log in again?

**What I do:** When the user logs in I save the access_token and the expiration time. Later, I can use the access_token when making API calls. This is all fine.

**The problem:** with offline_access not working anymore, the access tokens I get are valid for 60 days. This means that after 60 days they will stop working. Can I do something to renew those tokens without asking the user to login again?

**My research:**
I read the documentation, but it seems to mention only Android and iOS. While I assume it would be similar for Windows Phone, I am not able to find out what to do. The Facebook libraries for those other platforms have something like:

```
facebook.extendAccessTokenIfNeeded(this, null);
```

I was not able to find similar method for Windows Phone. While I read somewhere that this does not actually work for Android, it hints that there must be a way to do it.

I read about the new endpoint allowing renewing of access tokens, but it seems to only be able to extend short-lived tokens to long-lived. For me it is a bit unclear from the documentation here(Section 4):
https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the Offine Access Removal Guide on the link you provided. It has the API Call you can use to get a long-lived Access Token for the user - this is the replacement of `offline_access`.

Specifically, see Scenario 4.

In theory, Windows Mobile should fall under Exception 2 / 3. See if the Windows Mobile SDK has an option to access the access_token in a similar way to iOS and Android.

Comment: As I mentioned, I already read about the new endpoint for renewing tokens. It seems to work only for turning a short-lived token to a long-lived. Is this correct? I already have a long-lived token(60 days), the question is what to do to renew this before those days have passed and the user has to log in again?

Comment: You can use the same API call to extend the life of a long-lived token, as the documentation states.

Comment: Do you mean that I can use this new endpoint? Is this the API call you mean(section 4 of the link I posted)? If so, then the text there must be incorrect, because it says:
"Using the new endpoint below, you will be able to extend the expiration time of **an existing, non-expired, short-lived** user access_token. Please note, the endpoint **can only be used to extend the short-lived user access_tokens**. If you pass an access_token that had a long-lived expiration time, the endpoint will simply pass that same access_token back to you without altering or extending the expiration time."

Comment: I guess that means you have to get a new short-lived access_token from the user when they next login. It means you must gracefully reject tokens older than 60 days, and wait for the user to login again.

Comment: Well, thanks, but we are then back to my original question: **how to keep using the Facebook API on the next launch of the app without having the user to log in again?**

Or is it not possible?

Comment: You can keep using it using the long-lived access token until it expires. After which, you won't be able to access the API until the user logs in again.